# Add rules to Microsft Outlook contextual Add-In

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to make a dicitionary-like contextual Outlook add-in. For example, somebody gets an email with an acronym (our company uses a lot of them) like "GIS" it turns to "Geographical Information System".

I know how to add this rule in the manifest.xml, but i would like to add the rules without reinstalling the add-in, because the list is constantly growing.

Is it possible somehow to add them from a JSON in the app.js or reach this goal without modifying the manifest itself?

Comment: "because the list is constantly growing"   I think, after a week you should have most acronyms, and restarting one time a day should be sufficient.  Please share more info why you think restarting more often is REALLY needed.

Comment: @Luuk If i get suggestions to add new acronyms for the rule list, i can't do it without reinstalling the Add-In. This is why i asked this.

Comment: @Luuk Nowhere does he mention `restarting`. While close to `reinstalling` they are in fact, quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible currently.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.